# If an undirected graph consists of a cycle, then what is the starting point of the cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I was recently trying to code up the following problem :

Given an undirected graph G = (V,E) design an algorithm to check if the graph consists of a cycle or not. The problem is fairly simple and one can use any of the Graph search algorithms BFS or DFS to solve this.

However while coding up the condition for checking if an edge leads to cycle formation in BFS algorithm I started to think about the following problem :

***What if someone asks us to find out the starting point of the cycle quickly?***

I tried to come up with a way to detect the starting point of the cycle and after some rough drawings came to the conclusion that the starting point of the cycle will be the Lowest Common Ancestor of the two vertices the edge between whom leads to the formation of the cycle. And now there are two things in my mind that I want to find out for myself :

1. Is this claim correct firstly?
2. If the claim is correct how should one go about proving this?

Here is a rough sketch I came up with to build some intuition :

[image: Detecting Cycle in an Undirected Graph]

I apologize for such a long question, but I would like to thank in advance to anyone who answers it or takes a stab at it :).

Comment: by LCA I mean LCA in the BFS tree obtained by executing BFS on the graph

Comment: "starting point of a cycle"?  Cycles are *cyclic*; every vertex of a cycle is an equally valid starting point.  Alternatively, you have a definition of the term "starting point" differing from its natural language meaning, and that definition is missing from your Question.

Comment: To me, "consists of a cycle" means it is only a cycle; it shouldn't have those linear branches. Maybe you meant "contains a cycle"?

Comment: @EricTowers : yeah may be you are right, it may be the case that the way I was drawing the graph led me to ask that question but I totally agree that in a cycle each vertex has an equal probability of being the starting vertex of the cycle and hence culminating into the conclusion that there is no starting point of the cycle. But is there a way to massage the question such that the answer is 3 which is the LCA in this case? Like what would be the fundamental question to ask if 3 were the expected answer in this case?

Comment: You miss something. There is no such thing like a *starting point* in a cycle. Neither a *probability to be the starting point of the cycle*. Or define *starting point*.

Comment: *A* way to approach your idea of "3 were the expected answer" is: [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on your (immediate) ancestor relation and take the earliest sorted member of the cycle.  If your (immediate) ancestor relation is breadth-first, and you label vertices with the order they are visited, this is the vertex with the least label in the (eventually discovered) cycle.